# Managing New Application Requests

Tags: agile

At the moment we are a small development team of 2. All our software is used inhouse. Currently staff just walk to our desk when they want new software developed or when they want new features added to existing software, or when bugs arise.

I am looking for a better management process of this. Do I get staff to send an email instead and then that can be designated to a developer. Or is there a simple software app out there that could help?

I want a simple method for doing this as the staff are unlikely to use something if too time consuming or complex. They find it too easy to approach a developer personally!

Anything to recommend please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use JIRA. It has a feature where emails sent to a certain address can get turned in to backlog items (using the email subject line as the title).

Answer (score 0):

Keep it as it is for now: face-to-face communication is always better than using any piece of software...
It will be only when you will grow to more developers that you will really need such software: from online or cloud based (ie Zimbra) to VCSs (version control systems) hosted on your machines.